# Round timestamp to 30 minutes interval to group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

## Problem

```
select currency,
       MAX (CASE WHEN type = 'Bank A' THEN rate ELSE null END) as bank_a_rate,
       MAX (CASE WHEN type = 'Bank B' THEN rate ELSE null END) as bank_b_rate
from rates
group by currency, created
```

I want to group my data by currency, timestamp and show all type value like table of comparison with interval of 30 minutes, for now my created time is 1 minute or less different so if i group with created time it will still showing 4 rows cause of different timestamp, is there a way to round the timestamp ?

### Data Source

| Type | Currency | Rate | Created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bank A | USD | 3.4 | 2020-01-01 12:29:15 |
| Bank B | USD | 3.34 | 2020-01-01 12:30:11 |
| Bank A | EUR | 4.92 | 2020-01-01 12:31:01 |
| Bank B | EUR | 5.03 | 2020-01-01 12:31:14 |

### Expected Result

| Timestamp | Currency | Bank A Rate | Bank B Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 12:30:00 | USD | 3.4 | 3.34 |
| 2020-01-01 12:30:00 | EUR | 4.92 | 5.03 |

Comment: Which is your DBMS?

Comment: In mysql "group by round(timestamp(created)/1800)" should get you started in the right direction

Comment: @Stefanov.sm im using postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Truncate/round `created` to 30 minutes (the `ts` expression) and group by it. Your query with this amendment:

```sql
select date_trunc('hour', created) + 
       interval '1 minute' * (extract(minute from created)::integer/30)*30 AS ts, 
       currency,
       MAX (CASE WHEN "type" = 'Bank A' THEN rate ELSE null END) as bank_a_rate,
       MAX (CASE WHEN "type" = 'Bank B' THEN rate ELSE null END) as bank_b_rate
from rates
group by currency, ts;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/db713/8)

**'Inherit' previous rate**

```sql
select ts, currency, 
  coalesce(bank_a_rate, lag(bank_a_rate) over w) bank_a_rate,
  coalesce(bank_b_rate, lag(bank_b_rate) over w) bank_b_rate
from
(           
 select date_trunc('hour', created) + 
       interval '1 minute' * (extract(minute from created)::integer/30)*30 ts, 
       currency,
       MAX (CASE WHEN "type" = 'Bank A' THEN rate ELSE null END) as bank_a_rate,
       MAX (CASE WHEN "type" = 'Bank B' THEN rate ELSE null END) as bank_b_rate
 from rates
 group by currency, ts
) t
window w as (partition by currency order by ts);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/db713/19)

Comment: @basha04 Fully rewritten answer

Comment: Thanks, its works but do you how to take prev rate if one of the bank rate is still not available to prevent null value?

Comment: I would try using `coalesce` and `lag` on the result set.

Comment: i tried using lag but got error at ts variable for order, can u give me example ?

Comment: Added to answer.

Comment: thanks, do you have a way to get latest row more accurate rather than using max ?

Comment: Max seems OK to me in this case.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `epoch` for this purpose and then converting the seconds to 30 minutes intervals using arithmetic:

```
select '1970-01-01'::timestamp + floor(extract(epoch from created) / (24 * 60 * 2)) * (24 * 60 * 2) * interval '1 second' as timestamp,
       currency,
       MAX (CASE WHEN type = 'Bank A' THEN rate ELSE null END) as bank_a_rate,
       MAX (CASE WHEN type = 'Bank B' THEN rate ELSE null END) as bank_b_rate
from rates
group by timestamp, currency;
```

Comment: This will get a bit easier with Postgres 14 which provides a `date_bin()` function.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Follow your remark about `date_trunc()` I sketched one [here](https://github.com/stefanov-sm/timestamp-date_trunc).